# Can't Type Password in Terminal

Tags: command-line, password

When I type any command and after that it asks for password but I can't type that. For example in terminal I type sudo apt-get update and after pressing enter, it asks for password. I type password but nothing appears in the terminal. Whatever i type it don't get typed in case of password. And for each command it asks for password. Any Solution for this?

Comment: This is how it works. The password is not echoed even with stars. Just type your password and hit Enter.

Comment: @chaskes I think it's a security precaution, i.e. the length of the password shouldn't be known either.

Comment: @chaskes Nope. This question asks for a solution, and there is pretty much nothing which can be added to the answer. I don't want to spark a discussion like "why shouldn't the length of the password be known either?"

Answer (score 4):

It's typed, but you don't see stars. Try typing it then hitting Enter. Does it help?

Comment: @TrueBeliever Remember to click the checkmark if this solved your problem.